# How to create a user in Firebase using golang?

Tags: go, firebase, firebase-authentication

Is there any way to create a user in Firebase using Userame, Email and Password with Golang. A user can be created with Javascript using `createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` But I need the same with Golang. Is there a package or function available? I am using firego to connect with Firebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase has added an Admin SDK for Go. See Mujtaba's answer for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47889860

---

Previous answer:

<strike>There is no Firebase SDK for Go. But certain parts of Firebase have a REST API that allows you to use those features from almost any platform/technology. The Firebase Database is one of those features and the Firego library is a wrapper around the REST API of the Firebase Database for Go developers.</strike>

Unfortunately there is no REST API for creating users in Firebase Authentication. So it won't be possible to create users through Firego or through a public REST API from your Go code.

The simplest solution would be to create a REST endpoint on a app server you control, where you then use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/) to [create the user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user).

Comment: do we have any other reference to create a user in firebase in golang?

Answer (score 20):

Recently Google added Go Lang to their list of programming languages that are supported by Firebase Authentication using [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/).

To create a user:

```
params := (&auth.UserToCreate{}).
        Email("user@example.com").
        EmailVerified(false).
        PhoneNumber("+1234567890").
        Password("secretPassword").
        DisplayName("Donald Drump").
        PhotoURL("http://www.example.com/12345678/photo.png").
        Disabled(false)
u, err := client.CreateUser(context.Background(), params)
if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error creating user: %v\n", err)
}
log.Printf("Successfully created user: %v\n", u)
```

if you want to create a user with your own user ID and don't want an automated generated ID by Firebase then:

```
params := (&auth.UserToCreate{}).
        UID(uid).
        Email("user@example.com").
        PhoneNumber("+1234567890")
u, err := client.CreateUser(context.Background(), params)
if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error creating user: %v\n", err)
}
log.Printf("User created successfully : %v\n", u)
```

to update a user:

```
params := (&auth.UserToUpdate{}).
        Email("user@example.com").
        EmailVerified(true).
        PhoneNumber("+1234567890").
        Password("newPassword").
        DisplayName("Donald Drump").
        PhotoURL("http://www.example.com/12345678/photo.png").
        Disabled(true)
u, err := client.UpdateUser(context.Background(), uid, params)
if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error updating user: %v\n", err)
}
log.Printf("Successfully updated user: %v\n", u)
```